# Does the the 'linux' version of arm gcc compiler support -cpu=cortex-m4?

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, arm64

I am using aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc for compiling the applications on my Ubuntu 20.04. It has support for cortex-a and few other processor cores. But not on cortex-m4 (or cores which use armv7. Can anyone recommend or provide a link to the compiler installer which supports cortex-m4?

Comment: The arm64 and arm32 are completely different languages and backends.  You need the arm32 gcc and you can target 'cortex-m4'.  The other issue is the 'library' and OS.  For some projects you can ignore these by using the `-freestanding` option.  This is unlike the x86 which has an `-m32` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler for 32-bit ARM on Ubuntu is `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` or `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, roughly according to whether you want to compile code to run on a Linux OS or on bare metal.  Look for the packages `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` or `gcc-arm-none-eabi`.

The `aarch64` compilers only support 64-bit ARM.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I downloaded gnueabihf and was able to get the option of mcpu with value cortex-m4. However, the compilation all fails.                                                  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 hello.c -o hello_32
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: error: /tmp/ccq5QJWA.o: conflicting architecture profiles M/A
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /tmp/ccq5QJWA.o
But when i specify v8 arch proc, no error

Comment: @TomJose: Oh sorry, the Cortex-M4 has no FPU, so you need `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` instead (no `hf` which is "hardware floating point").  Then the command will be `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`.  That compiles for me with `-mcpu=cortex-m4`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response. I will try it. Also, one last doubt, i could see that cortex m4 has an optional fpu support which is coined by m4f. If i need to compile on m4f as target, then do i need to use gnueabihf or use gnueabi with mfpu flags? Once again thank you very much

Comment: I don't know, sorry.  You should ask that as a new question.

Comment: no problem. You were really helpful. I greatly appreciate it. Thank you.